# R: Change rows in dataframe if value repeats after n elements

Tags: r, rows

I have a very big dataframe **Data** where I need to check if **Energy** repeats within n steps. You can see that Energy is zero again after n steps, witch is what I need to change. I set n to 10 in the example. I need to do this because it is an error in a messurement.

Below is the code I came up with but it takes too long for my hole data to complete.

Here is an extrakt of my data so you can test it:

```
Date <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-03 01:00:00", "2017-06-03 01:15:00", "2017-06-03 01:30:00","2017-06-03 01:45:00","2017-06-03 02:00:00", "2017-06-03 02:15:00", "2017-06-03 02:30:00","2017-06-03 02:45:00","2017-06-03 03:00:00", "2017-06-03 03:15:00", "2017-06-03 03:30:00","2017-06-03 03:45:00","2017-06-03 04:00:00", "2017-06-03 04:15:00", "2017-06-03 04:30:00","2017-06-03 04:45:00","2017-06-03 05:00:00", "2017-06-03 05:15:00", "2017-06-03 05:30:00","2017-06-03 05:45:00","2017-06-03 06:00:00", "2017-06-03 06:15:00", "2017-06-03 06:30:00","2017-06-03 06:45:00","2017-06-03 07:00:00", "2017-06-03 07:15:00", "2017-06-03 07:30:00","2017-06-03 07:45:00","2017-06-03 08:00:00","2017-06-03 08:15:00"))
Energy <- c(0,0,0,0,150,149,149,146,147,146,142,5,0,0,0,0,5,14,37,55,54,94,82,127,197,NA,256,195,219,220)
Sun <-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,11,23,34,34,31,34,41,75,107,111,104,141,107,199,197,180,241,190,153,150)
Data <- data.frame(Date, Energy, Sun)
```

There are also NA values in the list and I need to consider them too. I put one value NA for this example.

```
n <- 10
for (m in c(1:length(Data[[1]]))) {

    if (Data$Energy[m] == 0 && !is.na(Data$Energy[m])) {

      for (l in c(1:n)) {
        if (m+l > length(Data[[1]])) {
          break()
        }
        if (Data$Energy[m] == Data$Energy[m + l] && !is.na(Data$Energy[m + l])) {
          for (j in c(1:(l-1))) {
            Data$Energy[m + j] <- 0

          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I am sure there is an easier way to solve this but I don't know how since I am new to R. I mean I use if and for so much, it can´t run fast. It is really important that the code runs faster because I have over 2 000 000 elements in the Dataframe.

I get this result (which I want, but takes a long time):

```
Data
                  Date Energy Sun
1  2017-06-03 01:00:00      0   0
2  2017-06-03 01:15:00      0   0
3  2017-06-03 01:30:00      0   0
4  2017-06-03 01:45:00      0   0
5  2017-06-03 02:00:00      0   0
6  2017-06-03 02:15:00      0   0
7  2017-06-03 02:30:00      0   0
8  2017-06-03 02:45:00      0   0
9  2017-06-03 03:00:00      0   1
10 2017-06-03 03:15:00      0   5
11 2017-06-03 03:30:00      0  11
12 2017-06-03 03:45:00      0  23
13 2017-06-03 04:00:00      0  34
14 2017-06-03 04:15:00      0  34
15 2017-06-03 04:30:00      0  31
16 2017-06-03 04:45:00      0  34
17 2017-06-03 05:00:00      5  41
18 2017-06-03 05:15:00     14  75
19 2017-06-03 05:30:00     37 107
20 2017-06-03 05:45:00     55 111
21 2017-06-03 06:00:00     54 104
22 2017-06-03 06:15:00     94 141
23 2017-06-03 06:30:00     82 107
24 2017-06-03 06:45:00    127 199
25 2017-06-03 07:00:00    197 197
26 2017-06-03 07:15:00     NA 180
27 2017-06-03 07:30:00    256 241
28 2017-06-03 07:45:00    195 190
29 2017-06-03 08:00:00    219 153
30 2017-06-03 08:15:00    220 150
```

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Hi, if you want to efficently code in R, I would suggest you to use apply functions (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply)  or map functions (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map)  instead of so many for loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I've understood correctly because your description of the problem doesn't quite match what your code is doing but it seems that you want a window of values to be set to zero if it's book-ended by zeros.  If that's the case, you can accomplish this fairly quickly and easily with indexing.

```
# Window size
n <- 10

# Find zeroes
zeros <- which(Data$Energy == 0)

# Find distance between zeroes
dist.zero <- diff(zeros)

# Generate index sequences of windows to change
idx <- unlist(lapply(which(dist.zero > 1 & dist.zero <= n), function(x) zeros[x]:zeros[x+1]))

# Replace values
Data$Energy[idx] <- 0
```

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot thank you. Now I have the problem that sometimes values greater than zero show the same pattern. I don't know how to mordify the code to replace the changed value at the right spot. Exaple: Energy1 <- c(5,10,100,200,150,50,30,5,5,5,10,20,40,100,200,200,200,150,50,30,25,20)

Answer (score 1):

The following code is faster than the question's solution.
Instead of nested `for` loops it loops once only with `sapply` and determines repetitions with `dplyr::lead`. Then the fast `rowSums` gets the elements of column vector `Energy` that need to be changed.

```
n <- 10

eq <- sapply(seq.int(n), function(l){
  z <- Data[["Energy"]] == dplyr::lead(Data[["Energy"]], n = l, default = 0)
  z | Data[["Energy"]] == 0
})

eq[is.na(eq)] <- FALSE
inx <- rowSums(eq) != 0
inx <- which(inx)
if(length(inx) > 0) {
  Data[["Energy"]][min(inx):max(inx)] <- 0
}
Data
```

After running this code, the two vectors that were created are no longer needed.

```
rm(eq, inx)    # tidy up
```